# Why reducer must return new state?

Tags: redux

Why reducer must return new state what is the reason for that .Why can't we return  the updated state? Is that the pattern that we must follow or what?Also please let me know that ngrx and redux are they completely different?

Comment: Yes it is the pattern you must follow. In redux the state is immutable for a few different reasons.

They even have a section about it in their documentation!
https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data

Answer (score 2):

I think because the view layer needs to compare current state and previous state, they should be different objects. Also, it can support other features like debugging, time travel.

Answer (score 1):

In both the library, They return a newly modified state or the original state

Just going through the official docs of both [NgRX reducer](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers) and [Redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

**NGRX Reducer**

> Reducers in NgRx are responsible for handling transitions from one state to the next state in your application.
>
> Reducer functions are pure functions in that they produce the same output for a given input. They are without side effects and handle each state transition synchronously. Each reducer function takes the latest Action dispatched, the current state, and determines whether to return a **newly modified state or the original state**

**Redux Reducer**

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store.

Regardless of the state management pattern, You need to change the state through reducers as actions are responsible fpr source of information for the store. They are the entry points to interact with store in Both `NgRx` and 'redux', moreover in `Vuex` too.

As per the state management library implementation, I guess they both follow same principle of Actions, Reducer to update the state async. There might be some possibly they may have different feature.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both libraries aim to manage a state which is only manipulated in particular, predefined ways; reducers are the access they provide to the state.

By limiting the ability to manipulate the state directly, they make it easier to understand how a particular state was reached; it is always possible to reach a particular state by dispatching the same actions again, and a given state can only be reached as a result of the actions dispatched to state (at least, this is the ideal - impure* reducers would potentially lead to different states being reached from the same actions).

If we imagine a state manager which allowed functions to manipulate state, which is what would be required to return a mutated version of the original state, then it would be far more difficult to understand how a given state was reached, as the store could have been manipulated at any point by any function.

[This article](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles) gives a good overview of the key ideas behind redux and explains *why* redux does the things it does. Here are the relevant parts for your question:

---

**State is read-only**

The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened.

This ensures that neither the views nor the network callbacks will ever write directly to the state. Instead, they express an intent to transform the state. Because all changes are centralized and happen one by one in a strict order, there are no subtle race conditions to watch out for. As actions are just plain objects, they can be logged, serialized, stored, and later replayed for debugging or testing purposes.

---

**Changes are made with pure functions**

To specify how the state tree is transformed by actions, you write pure reducers.

Reducers are just pure functions that take the previous state and an action, and return the next state. Remember to return new state objects, instead of mutating the previous state. You can start with a single reducer, and as your app grows, split it off into smaller reducers that manage specific parts of the state tree. Because reducers are just functions, you can control the order in which they are called, pass additional data, or even make reusable reducers for common tasks such as pagination.

---

I have far less experience with ngrx, though as it seems like a redux-inspired store, I'll presume it follows more or less the same principles. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, in which case I can update this answer.

---

*An impure function function would do one or many of the following:

1. Access state other than the arguments it was passed
2. Manipulate the arguments it was passed
3. Contain a side effect - something which affects state outside of itself

Answer (score 0):

Mutating state is the most common cause of bugs in Redux applications, including components failing to re-render properly, and will also break time-travel debugging in the Redux DevTools. Actual mutation of state values should always be avoided, both inside reducers and in all other application code.

Use tools such as redux-immutable-state-invariant to catch mutations during development, and Immer to avoid accidental mutations in state updates.

Note: it is okay to modify copies of existing values - that is a normal part of writing immutable update logic. Also, if you are using the Immer library for immutable updates, writing "mutating" logic is acceptable because the real data isn't being mutated - Immer safely tracks changes and generates immutably-updated values internally.

[From Redux Doc.](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide)